# draw matrix as a table in python

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to generate a data matrix with python and wish to draw it as a table.
From IPython, I found a display api and it can display the matrix as a table. but I still prefer:
1. remove the row index col and col index row.
2. the data grid should split evenly.

I am think about matplotlib but not sure how to do it.I wish to do it in the same script so no need to paste it here and there!

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print pd.__version__

row = 6
col = row
matrix = np.zeros((row, col))
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        if i == 0:
            matrix[i][j] = 1
        else:
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j] + matrix[i][j-1]
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
display(df)
```

Current output is:

[image]

#### Updated

According to Brat's comments, I have updated my code for referenc:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

row = 7
col = row
matrix = np.zeros((row, col))
matrix = matrix.astype(int)
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        if i == 0:
            matrix[i][j] = 1
        else:
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j] + matrix[i][j-1]
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
#display(df)

w = 5
h = 5
plt.figure(1, figsize=(w, h))
tb = plt.table(cellText=matrix, loc=(0,0), cellLoc='center')

tc = tb.properties()['child_artists']
for cell in tc: 
    cell.set_height(1.0/row)
    cell.set_width(1.0/col)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

plt.show()
```

Output as bleow:

[image]

Comment: Please, what do you mean with "the data grid should split evenly" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With matplotlib you might consider using `table`, for example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

nx = 4
ny = 5
data = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(ny,nx))

pl.figure()
tb = pl.table(cellText=data, loc=(0,0), cellLoc='center')

tc = tb.properties()['child_artists']
for cell in tc: 
    cell.set_height(1/ny)
    cell.set_width(1/nx)

ax = pl.gca()
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works but the number is displayed as float,e.g 1 will be printed as 1.0.

Comment: That's strange, which Python/matplotlib version are you using? At least with my matplotlib version (1.9.2), `matplotlib.text` does a conversion from `cellText` to the label as `'%s'%(s,)`, with `s` the raw value (string, int, float, ..) from `cellText`, so when I pass a `numpy.int64` from `randint` it is formatted as an integer, not a float. Only when I cast `data` to e.g. `np.float64` I get decimal numbers printed in the table.

Comment: Oh, I know what's wrong now. I need to convert matrix to integer (matrix = matrix.astype(int)".